# Ambiguous syntax of $this->$variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, syntax, ambiguity

Please excuse me if this question has been asked before, but I tried searching for it with no satisfactory results.

I'm learning PHP (coming from a C++ background) and have come across the following ambiguity. The following two bits of code work exactly the same:

```
class A
{
    public $myInteger;
    public function __get($name) 
    { 
        return $this->$name; 
    }
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

and

```
class A
{
    public $myInteger;
    public function __get($name) 
    { 
        return $this->name; 
    }
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }
}
```

that is, in the class methods `$this->$name` and `$this->name` have the exact same function. I'm finding this a bit confusing, especially when considering that if you add the following code,

```
$myA = new A();
$myA->myInteger = 5;
$hereInt = $myA->myInteger;

echo "<p>" . $hereInt . "</p>";
```

it *only* works if there is no `$` before `myInteger`. Could someone please explain the rationale behind this?

Comment: did you mean to put both classes as Class A ?

Comment: Yes; only one of the two chunks of code is used at any one time, of course.

Comment: This is clearly-defined, there is no ambiguity behind it.

Comment: do a `var_dump($myA)` at the end, in each case. I think you'll spot the difference quite quickly.

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the tip Leigh. So essentially using `$this->name` *creates* the field `name`, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$this->$name` and `$this->name` do *not* mean the same thing. The first is using a locally scoped variable `$name` to access the field of `$this` whose name is whatever `$name` contains, while the second accesses the `name` field directly.

For example, the following will output `something`:

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->bar = 'something';

$baz = 'bar';
echo $foo->$baz;
```

In the case of `__get` and `__set`, `$name` contains the name of the property that was accessed at the call site; in your case, `myInteger`.

In your example, the `__get` and `__set` methods are actually superfluous, since `$myA->myInteger` is public and can be accessed directly. `__get` and `__set` are only needed to catch access attempts to a property that is not declared explicitly in the class.

For example, you might have a backing array that allows arbitrary "properties" to be set dynamically:

```
class Foo
{
    private $_values = array();

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_values[$key]))
        {
            return $this->_values[$key]
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_values[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

One thing that's somewhat confusing about this aspect of PHP's syntax is that a `$` precedes a field declaration in a class, but there is none when accessing that field. This is compounded by the syntax for accessing static fields, which *does* require a `$`!

Comment: I other words, they will mean the same if, and only if `$name == 'name'` (variable `$name` contains string `name`)

Comment: Alright, but it still works if you declare `myInteger` as private. I think I get what you mean, but why does it work with `$this->name`? I.e. what field does it access when it gets the value?

Comment: @Kristian: It accesses the `name` field rather than `myInteger`. Obviously this means that any code that tries to assign to a field on that object will actually be accessing the same field, regardless of what name it specifies.

Comment: Right, so it creates the `name` field with that bit of code. I still gotta get used to this on-the-fly creation of variables; I find it a bit strange. Add to that the errors in the PHP book I'm reading and it becomes way tougher to comprehend.